# Android Service crash by calling via alarms

Tags: android, service, android-service

I want to start a service in background at particular time, for debugging i am starting the service at app launch but as soon as the service is started the app crashes with this exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.nexus.nsnik.gymchart.Downalod.VersionService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

My code:

```
private void setAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, VersionService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 46);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Service Class :

```
public class VersionService extends IntentService{

long version = 0;
DatabaseReference mRoot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mVersionChild = mRoot.child("version");
SharedPreferences spf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor spfe = spf.edit();

public VersionService(){
    super("versionCheckService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    mVersionChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            version = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if(version!=0){
                if(version!=spf.getLong(getResources().getString(R.string.versionNo),1089)){
                    startService(new Intent(VersionService.this,DownloadService.class));
                    spfe.putLong(getResources().getString(R.string.versionNo),version);
                    newDatabaseNotification();
                }else {
                    newDatabaseNotification();
                }
            }else {
                newDatabaseNotification();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void newDatabaseNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.newdatabase));
    NotificationManager mNotififcationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotififcationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me the line where the error is being shown?

Comment: where do you call the Context.getPackageName() method?

Comment: @KostasDrak i didnt call Context.getPackageName() anywhere

Comment: @KarunShrestha the error occur only if i call the versionservice class via alarms

Comment: but as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you are trying an `Intent` with `IntentService` and Class. You may want to see the constructors again

Comment: You can't initialize the `DatabaseReference` and `SharedPreferences` stuff there. You need to do it in a lifecycle method, like `onCreate()`. Furthermore, an `IntentService` stops itself when `onHandleIntent()` finishes, if it doesn't have any more pending tasks, so you probably want a regular `Service` instead.

Comment: @MikeM. so how do i perform that task in background if i dont put them in versionservice class

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by moving the database refrence and prefrence initilization in onCreate and alos move the code from onBind to onCreate since for some reason the code was not being executed.

```
public class VersionService extends Service{

long version = 0;
DatabaseReference mRoot;
DatabaseReference mVersionChild;
SharedPreferences spf ;
SharedPreferences.Editor spfe;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mRoot =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mVersionChild = mRoot.child("version");
    spf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    spfe = spf.edit();
    checkVersion();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void checkVersion(){
    mVersionChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            version = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (version != 0) {
                if (version != spf.getLong(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.versionNo), 1089)) {
                    startService(new Intent(VersionService.this, DownloadService.class));
                    spfe.putLong(getResources().getString(R.string.versionNo), version);
                    newDatabaseNotification();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


private void newDatabaseNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.newdatabase));
    NotificationManager mNotififcationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotififcationManager.notify(0,mBuilder.build());
}

}
```